# Seeking geospatial library for .NET Core?

Tags: software-recommendations, .net

I am trying hard to find any geospatial library that supports .NET Core, however with no success so far. Do you have tips for any?

My requirements are:

- work with different coordinate systems
- compute intersection of 2 geometries
- compute buffer of a polygon/polyline
- compute polygon area
- compute length of a polyline

Comment: Not sure if SQLServer types can do all this, but if so, have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48362174/125400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite). This library is used internally by Entity Framework Core for spatial operations.